# Tracing the references for a specific object in Python (memory leak)

Tags: python, memory-leaks

I have a 3rd party library creating huge memory leaks. I've called `gc.collect`, and have no references to any objects created by this library, but it still leaks.

Using `gc.get_objects()` I've identified numerous objects which should not be alive, as they are specific to this library.

How can I trace which objects are keeping these leaked objects alive (the goal being to trace it to a global variable/list, which I can reset to fix the leak)?

Files and line numbers would be nice, but even having the instances of the holder objects would help a great deal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [`gc.get_referrers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.get_referrers). Demo:

```py
import gc

def test():
    a = ['foo', b := {'bar'}]
    for r in gc.get_referrers(b):
        print(r)

test()
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY38zNzC_KLShTSk7m4UlLTFEpSi0s0NK24FIAgUcFWIVo9LT9fXUchScHKVqFaPSmxSL02Fiybll-kUKSQmQfUqpeeWhJflJqWWlSUWlSskQTVDwIFRZl5JRpFmlxcEJMh1kJth7kCAA)):

```
['foo', {'bar'}]
```